# Adding a <route> in custom module's webapi.xml breakes SOAP API

Tags: php, error, magento2.4, soap

I have my custom module with a `webapi.xml` file in module's `/etc` folder. The moment I add a`<route>` tag inside of the `<routes>` tag. The `http://<magento_host>/soap/default?wsdl_list=1` returns and error.

[image]

The route I was for example trying to add is

```
<route method="GET" url="/V1/rest_dev/square/:num">
    <service class="Learning\MyFirstModule\RestApi\Api\SquareNumber" method="getSquareNumber"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

Where the interface contains a simple method returning a suare of a given number

```
<?php

namespace Learning\MyFirstModule\RestApi\Api;

/**
 * Interface SquareNumber
 * @api
 */


interface SquareNumber
{

    /**
     * Returns square value of a number
     *
     * @param  int $num number to be squared
     * @return int
     */
    public function getSquareNumber(int $num): int;
    
}
```

And the class that implemetns it.

```
<?php

namespace Learning\MyFirstModule\RestApi\Api\Model;

use Learning\MyFirstModule\RestApi\Api\SquareNumber;

class SquareNumberCalculator implements SquareNumber
{

    /**
     * @param  int $num
     * @return int square value of the number
     */
    public function getSquareNumber(int $num): int
    {
        return $num * $num;
    }
}
```

My question is. What causes this? And how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was that the interface name was missing **`Interface`** at the end. The name should be the **`SquareNumberInterface`** instead of `SquareNumber`. Didn't think that in particular would be the problem, but turns out it was.